# check amount of time between different rows of data (time) and date and name of employee

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with this info ['Name', 'Department', 'Date', 'Time', 'Activity'],
so for example looks like this:

[image: raw data]

Acosta, Hirto     225 West 28th Street  9/18/2019  07:25:00   Punch In
Acosta, Hirto     225 West 28th Street  9/18/2019  11:57:00  Punch Out
Acosta, Hirto     225 West 28th Street  9/18/2019  12:28:00   Punch In

Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/16/2019  06:57:00   Punch In
Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/16/2019  12:00:00  Punch Out
Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/16/2019  12:28:00   Punch In
Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/16/2019  15:30:00  Punch Out
Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/18/2019  07:04:00   Punch In
Adams, Juan     225 West 28th Street  9/18/2019  11:57:00  Punch Out

I need to calculate the time between the punch in and the punch out in the same day for the same employee.
i manage to just clean the data
like:

```
    self.raw_data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(self.raw_data['Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.time
    sorted_db = self.raw_data.sort_values(['Name', 'Date'])
    sorted_db = sorted_db[['Name', 'Department', 'Date', 'Time', 'Activity']]
```

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Include your sample data as text, not picture. Otherwise your question is likely to get downvoted/closed

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name','Date'])['Hour'].diff()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the answer of my problem and i wanted to share it.

first a separate the "Punch in" and the "Punch Out" if two columns

```
    def process_info(self):

    # filter data and organized --------------------------------------------------------------
    self.raw_data['in'] = self.raw_data[self.raw_data['Activity'].str.contains('In')]['Time']
    self.raw_data['pre_out'] = self.raw_data[self.raw_data['Activity'].str.contains('Out')]['Time']
```

after i sort the information base in date and time

```
        sorted_data = self.raw_data.sort_values(['Date', 'Name'])
```

after that i use the shift function to move on level up the 'out' column so in parallel with the in.

```
        sorted_data['out'] = sorted_data.shift(-1)['Time']
```

and finally i take out the extra out columns that was created in the first step. but checking if it is by itself.

```
        filtered_data = sorted_data[sorted_data['pre_out'].isnull()]
```